# Text elements wiggle up/down when toggling the visibility of input element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a layout which looks like:

```
<ul id="playlists" class="ui-sortable">
    <li data-id="b69c8348-f47c-4156-a975-a2f1009610a8" data-type="3" class="listItem playlist active"><i class="fa fa-list fa-fw"></i>
        <span class="title" title="">
            Playlist 0000
        </span>
        <input type="text" value="Playlist 0000" class="editableTitle hidden" maxlength="255" />

        <span class="count">0</span>
    </li>
</ul>

$('.title').click(function(){
    $('.title').hide();
    $('.hidden').show();
});

$('.hidden').blur(function(){
    $('.title').show();
    $('.hidden').hide();
});
```

and here's a JS fiddle which shows the issue (tested in latest version of Chrome):

http://jsfiddle.net/3WEHJ/14/

Whenever I toggle the visibility of the hidden input, the font-awesome icon wiggles up and down.

I'm able to align it with some vertical-align tricks, but it then becomes mis-aligned when the input is hidden again. Is there a way to support both scenarios with some simple CSS?

Comment: Try to adjust `line-height` property to `#playlists span.title, #playlists input.editableTitle`...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to ensure that the line-height of the input element corresponds to the line-height of its surrounding text elements. My font-awesome icon has a line-height of 14px and the input element's line-height was undefined, but implicitly assumed to be 16px. By setting it to 14px and then aligning the two, no more flickering.